# Is there any module in Erlang to find the BFS and parent-BFS sequence of a graph in Erlang?

Tags: graph, module, erlang, breadth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

Is there any module in Erlang to find the BFS and parent-BFS sequence of a graph?

```
For example, 
for the Graph [[0,7,0,0,1],[7,0,6,0,5],[0,6,0,2,3],[0,0,2,0,4],[1,5,3,4,0]]:


So the result should be :

the BFS sequence is [1,5,2,3,4] for root 1 and parent-BFS sequence should be [0,1,5,5,1]
```

The data structure I am using is a list of lists to store the graph. And the result is also expected to be in a list(However, this is flexible)

I already have written the code for parent-BFS sequence as follows:

```
-module(prog).
-export([main/0,createlist/2,createlistbool/2,dense/5,populate/5,bfs/4]).

createlist(L,0) ->
    L;
createlist(L,Sz) ->
    List = lists:append(L,[0]),
    createlist(List,Sz-1).
    
createlistbool(L,0) ->
    L;
createlistbool(L,Sz) ->
    List = lists:append(L,[false]),
    createlistbool(List,Sz-1).

dense(_,_,0,Q,_) ->
    Q;
dense(X,L,N,Q,Viz) ->
    Child = lists:nth(N,L),
    case ( Child =/= 0 ) of
        true -> 
               case ( lists:nth(N, Viz) == false ) of
                    true -> Qu = queue:in({N,X},Q);
                    false -> Qu = Q
               end;
        false -> Qu = Q
    end,
    dense(X,L,N-1,Qu,Viz).

populate(_,_,Ans,_,0) ->
    Ans;
populate(Graph,Q,Ans,Viz,F) ->
    case ( queue:is_empty(Q) == false ) of
        true -> {X,Y} = queue:get(Q),
                Que = queue:drop(Q),
                case ( lists:nth(X,Viz) == false) of
                   true ->
                          Answer = lists:sublist(Ans,X-1) ++ [Y] ++ lists:nthtail(X,Ans),
                          Vizible = lists:sublist(Viz,X-1) ++ [true] ++ lists:nthtail(X,Viz);
                   false ->
                          Answer = Ans, Vizible = Viz
                end,
                Flag = F,

                C = lists:nth(X,Graph),
                Qu = dense(X,C,length(Graph),Que,Vizible);
        false -> 
                Answer = Ans, Vizible = Viz, Flag = 0, Qu = Q
    end,
    populate(Graph,Qu,Answer,Vizible,Flag).
    
bfs(Graph,Node,Ans,Viz) ->
    Q = queue:new(),
    Qu = queue:in({Node,0},Q),
    Answer = populate(Graph,Qu,Ans,Viz,1),
    Answer.
    
main() ->
  % your code goes here
  N = 5,
  Graph = [[0,7,0,0,1],[7,0,6,0,5],[0,6,0,2,3],[0,0,2,0,4],[1,5,3,4,0]],
  Viz = createlistbool([],N),
  Ans = createlist([],N),
  Root = 1,
  Answer = bfs(Graph,Root,Ans,Viz),
  Answer.
```

However, I am looking for if there exists any module that performs the same?

Comment: Your question does not comply to this forum's rule. You should explain what is your data structure, what you tried so far, where you are blocked. Please look at [Stackoverflow Help Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Otherwise you may have a look at [erlang-algorithms](https://github.com/aggelgian/erlang-algorithms), its is quite old but it seems to implement BFS, and [erlang algorithm documentation](http://aggelgian.github.io/erlang-algorithms/)

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my question. I have already written a code for finding the necessary in Erlang, but I was looking if I can do this without a from-scratch code, and if there is a library which I can use directly.